# ALSAMIXER - corrupt file

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, alsa

Noob here, just getting set up for using our first rpi, and trying to use a usb webcam to record audio. We bought a starter kit, with Raspbian Jesse. Video works great from the webcam, but when we tried to test the audio, we get a strange error.

`unexpected char: toplevel` and `home/pi/asoundrc corrupted consider removing or fixing it`

We haven't touched anything other than updating and upgrading the pi.
We've tried removing and purging ALSA, updating ALSA, to no avail.

Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Can you please show how you're capturing both the video and audio data? ie. What command/tool are you using, and how are you using it?

Comment: Please show the exact contents of the `/home/pi/.asoundrc` file.+#

Comment: Went ahead and re-flashed the SD, works this time around. Thanks CL. + stevieb